# Possible to regrout floor to change its color?

Tags: tile, floor, grout

The grout is not the color I want. It turned midnight blue and I want charcoal grey or black. I was at work when the workers grouted the floor. Can we grout with darker color over this blue and it work? It’s only been about 12 hours since it was first done.

Comment: It's rare, but I have seen dark grout get darker after drying .  Perhaps wait longer than the 12 hrs.  Give it 2 days and see if it has become more black.   Did you check the bag and verify the grout was blue and not black.   Black is fairly common, blue, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can for sure buy grout stain. It comes in tons of colors/shades, it's a lot more cost effective, and it's relatively easy to use. Re-grouting a floor isn't an easy job by any means, it's messy and very time consuming.The two main brands of grout stain and sealer I've used are Mapei and Aqua Mix. Both brands have a lot of color choices. Mapei is a little cheaper than Aqua Mix but the Aqua Mix seems to color better in my experience. It pretty much always took less of it to achieve the same result as the Mapei. Also, you should invest in some cheap knee pads and some rubber gloves. Crawling across tile on bare knees for a few hours is agonizing at best. I have worked in the construction/remodel industry for about 15 years and have recolored the grout on several floors. Aqua Mix is more expensive but it stains faster and darker with about half as much used.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll [edit] this to include a little formatting, it will be a lot easier to read and get the important bits of information out. As it stands, it's a hard to read wall of text...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot grout on top, it won't last.    You can dye it, black might work.   If not you can grind it out.  Or you can get RGB bulbs and set a warm light without much blue.  It will appear black.